# Как сделать фоновой рисунок в блоке через Style

Tags: php

Мне нужно сделать в блоке картинку а на ней текст. подскажите. тут нужно использовать команду в style background через него. пожалуйста помогите простите за то что не могу правильно сформулировать мысль

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css/background - читать от забора до обеда.

Answer (score 1):

```
background: URL('path_to_image') param;
```

Answer (score 0):

За фон любого элемента в **CSS** отвечает свойство

```
background-image: url(link_to_image);
```